# BindableProperty in ContentView not working

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I made a very simple Yes/No RadioBox control.

In it's code behind I have the following `BindableProperty`:

```
    public static readonly BindableProperty SelectedValueProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        "SelectedValue",
        typeof(int),
        typeof(YesNoView),
        0,
        BindingMode.TwoWay);
```

And it's property:

```
    public int SelectedValue
    {
        get { return (int) GetValue(SelectedValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedValueProperty, value); }
    }
```

This property is bound in the ContentView-XAML using something like this:

```
          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedValue}" Value="0" TargetType="Image">
            <Setter Property="Source" Value="radiobutton_checked.png" />
          </DataTrigger>
```

Whenever I use my ContentView in some Page and set the `SelectedValue` to a constant value, everything works fine!

However, when I use a `{Binding SomeValue}` instead of a constant value, where `SomeValue` is a property (with notify) on the Page I'm using the ContentView on, it will simply refuse to do anything. Whenever I set `SomeValue` to some value, it never reaches the ContentView and it's driving me insane why it isn't working.

Even when I adjust the BindableProperty to also specify a propertyChanged event, it is simply never triggered unless I revert back to a constant value in the Xaml, rather than a binding.

Could anyone shed a light as to why this is happening and not working as I would expect?

EDIT: I should add that in both the Page and the View the BindingContext is set to this.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I figured it out after a total of 4 hours wasted...

Never do `BindingContext = this;` in your ContentView, as it hijacks the context from the Page trying to databind to it. Instead use `Content.BindingContext = this;`

Comment: out of sheer curiosity: Could you explain what you mean with "hijack the context" and why this is a problem?

Comment: Or use the `Source` parameter for your binding.

Comment: @Sven-MichaelStübe: The page *using* the `ContentView` sets its `BindingContext` which will then be used for all child elements, including the custom `ContentView`. If you set the context in the content view again, you will overwrite it.

Comment: My problem wasn't that one, but was related to the BindingContext. I was assigning it in the wrong view. You solution helped me see other options. Thanks.

Comment: I was not sure either what was the problem and spent 5 hours on it, and this solved it! Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much for this! It's cleared up a lot of headaches!

Comment: Dude, you saved me from a working weekend. Thank you a lot.

Comment: That actually worked... How on earth did you figure that out?

Comment: It's been a long time @JonathanPeel, but at the time I saw countless of examples of people doing similar things like I was doing, and one of those did exactly this. So out of sheer desperation, I just tried it and voilà: I now have a very popular Q/A style question on SO :P

Comment: OMG i can't believe this, is there any documentation of this ?

Comment: @IronHide Not sure! But I'm glad this helped you :)